# What is the best way to say the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

The best way to say the following sentence?

> No matter how, to be deceived is not something one appreciates.

I want to say that "no matter how one is deceived, to be deceived is not something one appreciates." I want to say this in the most concise and most idiomatic way.

Comment: _No one likes being deceived, no matter how the deception takes place._

Answer (score 1):

How many multiple negatives do you want in your sentence? If you want to be clear would it not be better to be more direct? "Deception is bad, however it is dressed up."

Answer (score 1):

> Being deceived in anyway is something no one appreciates.
>
> Being deceived, no matter the situation, is something no one appreciates.
>
> Deceit in any fashion is enough to ruffle one's feathers.

Something like that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these ones for size:

> No matter when and how, no one likes being deceived.
>
> In general, people don't like it when somebody tries to deceive them.